# Twitter API Setting communication preferences for accounts with XAUTH

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth, linq-to-twitter

I wondered if anyone is aware of anyway that I may modify the communication settings of multiple Twitter accounts. Basically I have a number of accounts which all currently receive info at twitter emails etc and I'd like to manage these communication settings in an automated fashion but this doesn't seem to be possible.

I wondered if there is any way to do this in an automated fashion?

I'm using LinqToTwitter http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/ project to talk to the Twitter API in C#, although I don't necessarily have to use this.

I'm currently starting to think of using Selenium to do this.

Does anyone have any thoughts.

Many thanks,

Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some application settings you can manage through the API. In LINQ to Twitter they're mostly available by querying on the Application entity. However, there aren't any email preference setting options that the Twitter API offers.

My experience is that these settings options tend to change over time, mostly additive. So, whatever you come up with, you'll probably need to revisit your implementation occasionally to adapt to these changes.